# What is the meaning of #define abc (0-0)

Tags: c++, macros

Recently when writing code I encountered a problem. The code was something like this-

```
if ((var >= min) && (var <= max))
{
    return true;
}
```

Both min and max are macros already defined previously and var is an unsigned integer. I changed the value of min to 0, which generated a warning, **unsigned integer >= 0 will always be true**. 
First I thought to directly remove the first condition to take care of the warning, but my senior refused to do that, as the code is used in not only the project I am working but also other projects, so maybe the value of min may be above 0 in other projects. He suggested me to it like this-

```
#define min (0-0)
```

This solved the problem, no warning generated. But I did not understand why did it work? I asked my senior to explain but he said to find out on my own. I searched on google but did not find anything remotely familiar to it.
So can anyone explain to me what happened above?
Thank you in advance.

Comment: That is terrible advice. `min` is also a function that takes the minimum of two values.

Comment: What compiler and version is this?  I can't repro it with VC++ or g++ 7.5  with `-Wall`. (Although I've hit this exact warning before with various versions of g++). The right solution might be to suppress the warning. The compiler will obviously optimize out the expression.

Comment: Read [more about C++](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp), in particular the C++ standard [n3337](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2012/n3337.pdf). Read the [documentation of GNU `cpp`](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/cpp/) used by [GCC](http://gcc.gnu.org/)

Comment: First, to reply to @Botje's comment, I just have written min as an example, it does not mean min function, the actual name of the macro is minSomethingSomething

Comment: Next, @selbie, I am using g++, but am not sure about the version

Comment: `g++ --version`

Answer (score 1):

Answer: Because it seems the compiler doesn`t check the result of expressions.

Just to know: This is a problem. The compiler is correct - unsigned int can not be less than 0. Whatever you pass to this function, that comparison will always be true.
Because you are on work, do what the others tell you, but keep in mind - you are right, that should be removed, because it makes no sense in your current implementation.

Var has to be changed to long long and then everything will be fine! The problem is there!
It is a matter of time, someone to pass negative value to that function and will fail hard. It will make a warning for passing signed value to a function expecting unsigned and the guy will deprecate it to not have warnings ...

Comment: `var has to be changed to long long and then everything will be fine! ` is as bad as `0-0` if `var` has to be a none negative value with an upper bound of `max`. `It is a matter of time, someone to pass negative value to that function and will fail hard. It will make a warning for passing signed value to a function expecting unsigned and the guy will deprecate it to not have warnings` well yes, but not because it `val` is signed, but because the person ignores the warning.

Comment: `you are right, that should be removed, because it makes no sense in your current implementation.` that depends on the intent of the `min` macro, maybe the requirements are that the `var` is signed, with a lower bound that is currently `0` but might be any other value smaller than `max`, in future iterations of the code.

Comment: @t.niese, why changing the interface from 4 bytes unsigned to 8 bytes signed is a problem? I didn`t get.

Comment: If `var` is unsigned - which has to be true otherwise the warning would not be shown - then changing it to `long long` would change it to a signed type, and that why the warning would vanish. If you change it to `unsigned  long long` the warning would still be there. So with this suggestion, you silence the warning by changing the type of `var` form a `unsinged` to a `singed` type.

Answer (score 1):

`#define min (0-0)` and `#define min (0)` would be equivalent for type and value point of view.

It seems that it allows to break the check of your compiler.

Real fix to remove the warning is to handle the case, for example:

```
if constexpr (min == 0 && std::is_unsigned_v<std::decay_t<decltype(var)>>) {
    if (var <= max)
    {
        return true;
    }
} else {
    if (var >= min && var <= max)
    {
        return true;
    }
}
```

which is probably too verbose (and even worse if you do similar stuff for `max`).
That cure seems not better than the warning :-/

Possible workaround would be to wrap the test in a function,
as I don't think, currently, compilers warn about function returning always true in condition.

so:

```
// indirect comparison to avoid warning about always true comparison
if (std::less_equal<>{}(min, var) && std::less_equal<>{}(var, max))
{
    return true;
}
```

Comment: thanks for the fix, but actually I forgot to mention it, but this code is a part of embedded program, and in embedded, not many libraries are used.

Comment: Only std is used, and anyway can simply be rewritten.

Answer (score 0):

A macro applies a search and replace before compiling:

So for `#define min (0)` the code for the compiler will be:

```
if ((var >= (0)) && (var <= max))
{
    return true;
}
```

And for `#define min (0-0)` it will be:

```
if ((var >= (0-0)) && (var <= max))
{
    return true;
}
```

Both `var >= 0` and `var >= 0-0` are equivalent regarding the types involved in the comparsion.

`clang` will for example correctly report both with the warning `warning: result of comparison of unsigned expression >= 0 is always true [-Wtautological-unsigned-zero-compare]`.

`gcc` reports only the `(0)` case.

Using `0-0` is a bad idea, not only because silencing a warning instead of solving it is a bad idea, but also because that hack might fail in future compiler versions. It just does not solve the problem, but just tricks the compiler. And using macros to define constant also a bad idea.

By usning a `constexpr` for the constant instead of a macro the case of a `>= 0` could have been correctly solved.

Removing `var >= min` is not necessarily a good idea if the "constant" `min` exists, as someone could change its value the future. `var >= min` can only be safely removed the code should not rely on `min` and should never have a lower bound that is different to the one given by the type of `val`. So if `min` has any relevance then the code should be changed to handle the case when it is `0` correctly, so that the compiler is aware that you know that this case could exist.

Comment: Can you please explain to me, why is 0-0 is silencing the warning.

Comment: @ankitbansal because the current `gcc` compiler does not check if the type resulting of the expression `0 - 0` is singed or not. It just omits the check in that case. But because the check could technically be done, it is likely that the compiler will warn about that in a future version. It could be considered as a bug of the compiler.

Answer (score -1):

The #define is a red herring. It only affects situations where min is followed by parentheses, like int x = min (5, 7). It's not a good idea to have a variable with the same name as a macro, but it doesn't hurt you.

Whoever suggested changing the min macro is frankly an idiot. It will fatally break every bit of code that uses the min macro. If you tried that where I work we would have to discuss your further employment, that's how bad it is.

Your problem is that indeed if x is an unsigned variable and min = 0 the comparison x >= 0 will always be true. The compiler gives a warning which in your situation is stupid. A correct change instead if removing the condition would be (x == 0 || x > 0) instead of x >= 0; this will most likely remove the warning.

Comment: That is another hack. (future) compiler might also detect that the condition is always true for unsigned type.